# Magento search not working with - (hyphen)

Tags: magento2

I have lot of products with SKU like BM-A395NXIOXSA. When i try to search with the the SKU via search then result is not showing. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? The only solution I found was a very expensive Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Installing this patch might work for you.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050671611-MDVA-28993-Magento-patch-Elasticsearch-partial-search-minimum-should-match-and-fix-for-searches-with-hyphen-issue